# How to assign an Ajax response to a variable in another function in React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, reactjs

I have an ajax call that responds with a list of movies, and then I have an other function with an other ajax call that returns the genre names, since the first call only has the id of the genre, then I relate the genreId with its name and I assign it to the JSON on the first ajax call, kind of like assigning it to a variable. The problem that I have is that since ajax is asynchronous, it always ends up undefined. I don't want to make it synchronous since it will end up in a bad user experience.

> First ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        url: urlString,
        success: (searchResults) => {
            const results = searchResults.results

            var movieRows = [];

            results.forEach(movie => {
                movie.genres = this.getMovieGenres(movie.media_type, movie.genre_ids);

                const movieRow = <MovieRow key={movie.id} movie={movie}/>;
                movieRows.push(movieRow)
            });

            this.setState({rows: movieRows})

        },
        error: (xhr, status, err) => {
            console.log("Failed to fetch data...")
        }
    })
```

> Function that I call with the second ajax call

```
getMovieGenres (mediaType ,movieGenreIds) {

    urlString = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${config.movieDBbApiKey}&language=en-US`ApiKey}&language=en-US`

    var genres = []

    $.ajax({
        url: urlString,
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        method: "GET",
        success: searchResults => {
          for (let i = 0; i < movieGenreIds.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < searchResults.genres.length; i++){
              console.log(searchResults.genres[j].id)
              if (movieGenreIds[i] === searchResults.genres[j].id) {
                genres.push(searchResults.genres[j].name)
              }
            }
          }

        },
        error: (xhr, status, err) => {
            console.log("Failed to fetch data...")
        }
    })

  return genres

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are variouse solutions to your problem.

The simplest is to make the `second ajax call` in the callback of the `first ajax call`. In the second call you'll have **both results from first ajax call and the second**. Then make transforms and set state in the second call.

Other options (the reccomended one) is to work with `Axios` or `Fetch` that rely on Promises.
Promises can be evaded with Promise.all:

```js
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    return $.ajax({
        url: urlString,
        success: (searchResults) => {
            return resolve(searchResults.results)

        },
        error: (xhr, status, err) => {
            return reject("Failed to fetch data...")
        }
    })
})
```

function that return a promise

```
getMovieGenres (mediaType ,movieGenreIds) {

    urlString = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${config.movieDBbApiKey}&language=en-US`ApiKey}&language=en-US`

    var genres = []

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlString,
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            method: "GET",
            success: searchResults => {
                for (let i = 0; i < movieGenreIds.length; i++) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < searchResults.genres.length; i++){
                        console.log(searchResults.genres[j].id)
                        if (movieGenreIds[i] === searchResults.genres[j].id) {
                            genres.push(searchResults.genres[j].name)
                        }
                    }
                }

                return resolve(genres)

            },
            error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                return reject("Failed to fetch data...")
            }
        })
    }) 
}
```

finally:

```
promise().then(results => {

    var movieRows = [];
    var tasks = []

    results.forEach(movie => {
        tasks.push(getMovieGenres(movie.media_type, movie.genre_ids))
    });

    Promise.all(tasks).then(output => {
        output.forEach(movie => {
            const movieRow = <MovieRow key={movie.id} movie={movie}/>;
            movieRows.push(movieRow)
        })

        this.setState({rows: movieRows})
    })
})
```

Hope to help you!